# Alexa skill always fails the first time

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am writing my first Alexa skill and running into an issue.  When I test it in the Alexa Developer Console, the first time each utterance is called it will fail, then it will work fine after that.  For example:

```
User: Alexa, ask VHS if they are open
Alexa: Sorry, I didn't understand the command. Please try again. 
User: Alexa, ask VHS if they are open
Alexa: Yes, we are open
User: Alexa, ask VHS if the laser is in use
Alexa: Sorry, I didn't understand the command. Please try again.
User: Alexa, ask VHS if the laser is in use
Alexa: Laser is currently off 
User: Alexa, ask VHS if they are open
Alexa: Yes, we are open
```

My first thought was that since it is hitting a web API, it was moving on before the call was completed so I added an async/await pair around the `Request`, but that didn't help.

My code is on github here:  https://github.com/miststlkr/alexa-vanhack

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE that reproduces your problem? You can read about MCVE in the site help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but in summary it's a small program that illustrates the question you are trying to make. It's hard to expect us to visit your Github account to find out what's wrong with your program.

Answer (score 0):

I built your interaction model with one change, i.e, I used `v.h.s.` everywhere instead of `vhs` which is the standard way of defining abbreviations in Alexa.

And everything works fine. The request JSON was generated each time.

> The invocation name must contain only lower-case alphabetic
>   characters, spaces between words, possessive apostrophes (for example,
>   "sam's science trivia"), or periods used in abbreviations (for
>   example, "a. b. c.").

Comment: I still get "Sorry, I didn't understand the command. Please try again." the first time I invoke any Intent.  I even tried changing the invocation name from "VHS" to "VanHack" and "Van Hack"